# any good way to keep listenning the events of erc20 transfer and noticed by a url call

Tags: external-api

I think I can keep calling by etherscan to find new transactions and I the best way is that I can receive a url callback once an event created on erc20 token event log. Any API I can use for this? Or I must keep calling etherscan API for doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both `geth` and `parity` support Log filters. You can easily run a node and subscribe to the Transfer event for tokens you care about (or all Transfer events if you wish), and then pass that information onto whichever system needs it.

[eth_newFilter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter) will let you create this filter, and [eth_getFilterChanges](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getfilterchanges) will let you receive updates.

Answer (score 0):

[Cindercloud](https://docs.cinder.cloud/listen-for-transfers) has an API which allows you to do this. Internally,it uses geth and parity filters, but provides you with readable data.